# Search Document in "Pending"

Tags: 2007, configuration

Does SharePoint search the documents which are in state "PENDING" or "Draft" and which requires approval?

Answer (score 3):

Yes, SharePoint search shows documents with "PENDING" or "Draft" state, you have a workaround but it's only affects a specific list so if you need to remove results with "PENDING" or "Draft" versions on a specific list, you'll need to follow the next steps:

1. Go to List Settings.
2. Versioning Settings.
3. In the bottom section choose "Only users who can edit items".

[image: choose "Only users who can edit items"]

Make a full crawl and you won't see the "PENDING" or "Draft" items from that specific list again.

If you need to remove results with "PENDING" or "Draft" permanently, you'll need to implement a custom security trimming. Here's a great article on ["how to create a custom security trimmer for  Search"](http://extreme-sharepoint.com/2011/10/04/sharepoint-search-isecuritytrimmer/)!

Good luck.

Comment: Now one more problem in the document library, the documents in state Pending/Draft are being displayed in the Search when searched using the "Document Name", but when searched with the associated document number of the related document the search is not displaying the document.

Answer (score 0):

please see the below link .Hope this helps

http://www.sharepointblues.com/2010/03/17/draft-item-security-search-results-security-trimming/

Comment: Can you please summarize the solution in your answer and leave the link as a resource for additional information?